# WooCommerce pay for manually created orders without logging in

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I have a situation where customers cannot check out for manually created orders without logging in. When checking out via the direct pay link, if they are not logged in they are still able to see the order total and check out via PayPal or card, however when checking out via PayPal they will be returned to an empty cart page and when checking out via card, they will be sent to the page before the 3D secure redirect and thus their order will not be processed.

We had taken payments before in this way, via manually created orders and sending the customer the payment link however I believe updating Wordpress/PHP caused this error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this snippet will surely help to allow customer to pay without login in.
Please have a look over [here](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-allow-to-pay-for-order-without-login/)